# Razor is not if statement type does not exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting refType does not exist in the current content. I am passing it in as a parameter so I am not sure why I can't use it.

Calling function

```
$.each(references, function (index, item) {
    console.log(item);
    $(".references-list ol").append(referenceTmpl(item.Text, item.Link, item.RegimensCommaList, referenceIndex++, item.GuidelineId, item.GuidelineExternalReference, item.Type));
    buildReferences();
});
```

[image]

cshtml

```
function referenceTmpl(text, link, regimens, index, guidelineId, guidelineExternalReference,type) {
        var refType = type;
        @if (Model.Editable) {
            <text>var refDel = "<a href='#' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-reference' title='Delete'></a>";</text>
            if (refType = 'AMode')
            {
                <text>var refEdit = "";</text>
            }
            else
            {
                <text>var refEdit = "<a href='#' data-index='" + index + "' class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit edit-reference' title='Edit'></a>";</text>
            }

        } else {
            <text>var refDel = "";</text>
            <text>var refEdit = "";</text>
        }

    if (type == "A-Mode"){
        refEdit = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: @jerdine-sabio I updated the post.

Comment: Still lacks info, we don't know what `data` is. And where it comes from; script, controller, model.

Comment: it is part of items

Comment: i think, ``if (refType = 'AMode')`` must be ``if (refType == "AMode")``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line of code `var refType = type;` you are assigning a javascript variable to a razor template variable which won't work.

Try the code below;

```
function referenceTmpl(text, link, regimens, index, guidelineId, guidelineExternalReference,type) {
        <text>
            var refType = type;
            var refEdit = "";
        </text>
        @if (Model.Editable) {
            <text>
                var refDel = "<a href='#' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-reference' title='Delete'></a>";

                if(refType != 'AMode'){
                    refEdit = "<a href='#' data-index='" + index + "' class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit edit-reference' title='Edit'></a>";
                }
            </text>
        } else {
            <text>
               var refDel = "";
               var refEdit = "";
            </text>
        }

        <text>
            if (type == "A-Mode"){
                refEdit = "";
            }
        </text>
}
```

---

If you need to return a string value add `return refEdit+refDel;`;

```
function referenceTmpl(text, link, regimens, index, guidelineId, guidelineExternalReference,type) {
        <text>
            var refType = type;
            var refEdit = "";
        </text>
        @if (Model.Editable) {
            <text>
                var refDel = "<a href='#' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete-reference' title='Delete'></a>";

                if(refType != 'AMode'){
                    refEdit = "<a href='#' data-index='" + index + "' class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit edit-reference' title='Edit'></a>";
                }
            </text>
        } else {
            <text>
               var refDel = "";
               var refEdit = "";
            </text>
        }

        <text>
            if (type == "A-Mode"){
                refEdit = "";
            }


            return refEdit+refDel;
        </text>
}
```

Comment: The one way I can get it to work if I move the if statement out of that one why can I not add one under that @if

Comment: @Jefferson I also don't see the part where you're returning any data-- you're not returning a string. Your .append won't work because there's no return statement.

Comment: Correct there is a return just didnt add the full function just the problem section.

Comment: @Jefferson did you try the code above? I transferred the variable declarations to inside the text element. Adjusted how the variables are assigned as well.